# hide div when refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this `<div>` where I have an "X" which closes the `<div>` but shows up again upon refreshing the page. I want the `<div>` to stay hidden even after refreshing the page. How can I do that?

I want to hide them also when page is refreshed.

```
<div class="cookie">
    <a href="#" class="cookie-close">
    <span class="icon" onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>X</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: just add display:none to .cookie in your css

Comment: this hide my dive

Comment: Do you need to appear it only once ?

Comment: i want that when i click on "X" and close the parentNode and after refresh the page this remain closed

Comment: @hersugjima i have updated mmy answer accordingly or you can find [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/1633/) it'll definately help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add cookie there are some functions related to **CREATE** ,**READ** and **REMOVE** cookie please find this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/1633/) or below snippet for more information.

I hope it'll help you..

```js
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name,"",-1);
    }

   $(function(){
 
      if(readCookie('CodefireOnce') == null)
      {
        $(".cookie").css("display","block");
      }
      $("body").on("click",".icon",function(){
        $(this).closest("div.cookie").remove();
        createCookie('CodefireOnce','true',7);
      });
    });
```

```html
<div class="cookie" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" class="cookie-close">
    <span class="icon">X</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: @hersu gjima for future reference do the up vote the answer as well if you find it would be helpful to others

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing the option into localStorage, when the user clicks on x.

```
localStorage.setItem('showDiv', false)
```

hope this helps.. cheers

please consider the following code:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
    <div id="myDiv" class="cookie" style="display: none">
        <a href="#" class="cookie-close">
        <span class="icon" onclick='onClose()'>X</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script>
        function onLoad() {
            var showDiv;
            if(localStorage.getItem("showDiv") == null) {
                showDiv = true;
            }
            else {
                showDiv = localStorage.getItem("showDiv")
            }

            if (showDiv) {
                 document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('myDiv').remove();
            }
        }

        function onClose() {
            document.getElementById('myDiv').remove();
            localStorage.setItem("showDiv", false);
        }

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to be hidden everytime the page loads, just do as @FunkDoc said and add `display:none;` to your css. If you want it to open only on the first time you load the page, you have to save the details locally:

```
 // Retrieve
 if(localStorage.getItem("visited") == null){

    document.getElementsByClassName('cookie')[0].style.display = 'none';
 }

 // Store
 localStorage.setItem("visited", "true");
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mb06490w/1/

Answer (score 0):

you could make a script which looks a bit like this:

```
<div id="cookie_message" class="cookie" style="display: none;">
    <a href="#" class="cookie-close">
    <span class="icon" onclick="document.getElementById('cookie_message').style.display = 'none'; document.cookie = 'hideCookieMessage=true'; return false;">X</span>
    </a>
</div>
<script>
// checks if the cookie is NOT present, if not, then it shows the cookie message
if (!document.cookie.match(/^(.*;)?hideCookieMessage=[^;]+(.*)?$/)) {
   document.getElementById('cookie_message').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

It now only shows it when the cookie hideCookieMessage has not been set. Be sure to check in the backend as well for the cookie and don't even send it if the cookie is present.

Answer (score 0):

As Jersh and Adrian Bratu said, you could use the `localstorage` to store the state of your div (hidden or not).

But, I would suggest use a cookie instead.

The cookie allow you to have a expiration date where the localstorage is everlasting.
If, for whatever reason, you made changes in your div that you want the user to see eventually, using the localstorage, you'll have to clean it.

Which mean, either adding new data (with a date for example) to your storage.

Using a cookie, when the expiration date expire, the div will display again automatically, and you'll just need to set a new cookie with a new expiration date when it's expire.

The implementation is quite similar :

```
document.cookie = "hidden=true; expires=Fri, 20 Jan 2017 23:59:59 GMT"
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @MichaelMior pointed out in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703915/how-to-do-local-storage-for-to-do-list/ that local storage may not last longer then cookies, but the cookies are sent with browser requests so it's unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I see, didn't knew that. Thanks @Jersh ;)

Comment: I just discovered that as well. I could have used cookies with my php applications, but instead went with $_SESSION Variables and post requests, which aren't near as nice.

Answer (score 0):

Making it actually show the localstorage do what you want in here or in jsfiddle is iffy. What happens is, if you click the X, you hide the panel and save a variable on the localStorage. Then, when the page loads, you check for the presence of that variable. I've also added a "show" button so you can play with toggling the pane. I've set up a test page here https://snowmonkey.000webhostapp.com/cookieThing.html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
console.log("I've got "+localStorage.getItem("panelHidden"));
if(localStorage.getItem("panelHidden") == "true" ){
  $(".panel").hide();
} else {
  $(".panel-show-control").hide();
};

$(".panel-close-control").on("click", function(){
  // First, close the panel..
  $(".panel").hide();
  $(".panel-show-control").show();
  // then, set a cookie.
  localStorage.setItem("panelHidden", "true");
});

$(".panel-show-control").on("click", function(){
  // hide the button...
  $(this).hide();
  $(".panel").show();
  
  // then, unset the cookie!
  localStorage.setItem("panelHidden", "false");
});
  });
```

```css
.panel-close-control {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 9px;
  float: right;
}
.panel {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
  <span class="icon panel-close-control">X</span>
  <div class="pane-contents">
    <p>A designer can use default text to simulate what text would look like. Humans are creative beings. However, standard default text can do the trick. Your design looks awesome by the way. I hope you enjoyed the fake text. It looks even better with you
      using this text. Using default text is a simple way to create the appearance of content without having to create it. If it is not real text, they will focus on the design. This text will not appear in a consistent order. However, standard default
      text can do the trick.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="panel-show-control">
Show the panel
</button>
```